# Calling a feature with parameters within a JS function in Karate

Tags: karate

Since I'm using the older 0.8.x version of Karate, I'm trying to setup a polling test using the JS function. However, the parent feature would first make the call to a URL which returns the URI to hit for the status of a job. So I want to pass that to the called feature and make the call. Right now I have something like this:

```
Feature: caller
Background:
  * def waitForComplete = 
  """
       function(urlToHit) {
        var counter = 0;
        while(true) {
        if (counter > 2) {
           karate.log('failed');
           return false;
        }
        var result = karate.call('called.feature', { urlArg: urlToHit });
        if(result.status == 'DONE') {
          karate.log('success');
          return true;
        }
       }
      }
  """
Scenario: something
Given url xxxx
When method POST
Then status 202
And def urlPath = responseHeaders['location'][0]
And call waitForComplete urlPath
```

And my called feature is

```
Feature: called
Scenario: poll status
  Given url '#(urlArg)'
  When method GET
  Then status 200
```

However, the urlArg always shows as null. I have confirmed that the url is passed to the JS. But i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I have looked at the documentation
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v0.8.0/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature
https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/v0.8.0#calling-other-feature-files

Comment: works for me. follow this process if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks @peter-thomas Ok i'm chalking this up to being too tired or something. I tried again today and things work better. I didn't have to use the template syntax but rather just reference the variable as is. This question has been linked to a previously asked question which is unrelated except for both of them having to do with location header. I'm not savvy enough to figure out how to reopen it. But The answer is something where we can just say Given url  urlArg ... (from above JS json argument)